# Powerful .NET Map APIs?

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, gis

A coworker of mine thought of a great way to visualize a lot of the data we work with in our user-end applications, but we're not aware of many available sdk's or apis that hook in.

We're trying to recreate in essence, the "Magic-Wall" of CNN. We would like to be able to show trends across the country in a 'heat-map' kind of way, and be able to drill down into a state to show those same trends across counties. We don't need the move-states-all-over-the-place functionality that the commentators loved to use.

We're aware of Mappoint, but more research needs to be done if its capable of what we require.

Would it make more sense to just try and roll our own? Has anyone else tried something along these lines? The only problem I can see is defining the boundaries for each state, or by county on the state-level.

Thoughts? Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We ended up going with [SharpMap](http://www.codeplex.com/SharpMap).

Comment: SharpMap is a great open source library. Good choice.

Comment: Its been a while since you posted this comment. How are you finding SharpMap?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can take a look at Telogis GeoBase C# SDK, support WPF, WinForms and there is an XML/SOAP server for webservice implementations.

http://dev.telogis.com/

(I work for Telogis)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Manifold](http://www.manifold.net) GIS.  It is cheap and has a great SDK.

Comment: I can't find any details on their site about an SDK. They do mention ActiveX in their product description, are you sure this is a purely .NET based product.

Answer (score 1):

check out ESRI's product offering... ArcGIS Server and stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/

It's an asp.net user control

Comment: this is for a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with MapPoint and found it very robust - and there is a book on Amazon.  (Although it is a little dated, but still mostly works.)

I have also used GoogleMaps for web development.  If I'm not mistaken, I think that Google has released an API to allow GoogleEarth on web sites as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [CartoType](http://www.cartotype.com), our portable mapping library. There are CartoType SDKs for .NET, plain Windows, Android, iOS, Linux, and Mac OS.